# Как определить пинг пользователя, к серверу? Не от сервера к серверу, а от пользователя

Tags: php, ping

Как получить пинг зашедшего пользователя к необходимому серверу?...

```
exec('ping 3.3.3.3');// Определяет пинг от сервера где стоит хостинг к серверу 3.3.3.3
```

Например.

Мой ип: 1.1.1.1

Ип хостинга: 2.2.2.2

Ип куда нужно определить пинг: 3.3.3.3

---

От хостинга(2.2.2.2) к 3.3.3.3 пинг 100.

А от меня(1.1.1.1) к 3.3.3.3 пинг 50.

И если я захожу на сайт, и пытаюсь проверить пинг - мне выдаёт пинг 100, что вполне логично, так как если я захожу на хостинг то запросы идут от хостинга (2.2.2.2).

А как мне зайдя на свой сайт, получить пинг к серверу 3.3.3.3 от меня (1.1.1.1)(от клиента который зашел на сайт)

Comment: @splash58 обновил вопрос, добавил ясности

Comment: вы хотите именно через php  - думаю, никак

Comment: @splash58 причём здесь команда пинг на моём компьютере? Я привел пример того, как определить можно пинг, но это пинг определяется от хостинга к серверу, а не от меня к серверу.

Comment: через php вы ничего на своем компе не сделаете. поищите, возможно, можно это сделать через js, который на вашем компе работать будет. но не уверен

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить, что на самом деле вам нужно замерить время отклика.

Со стороны клиента(js) делаете запрос к своему серверу к скрипту заглушке, не выполняющему никакой сложной работы. Замеряете на клиенте время, прошедшее между отправкой запроса и получением ответа и отправляете его на сервер.

Comment: Судя по вопросу, все-таки это третий комп

Comment: Третий сервер не мой, третий сервер может быть любым сервером к которому нужно пинг проверить.
Допустим есть сайт со списком серверов майнкрафта, 100серверов есть, и каждому клиенту нужно показать пинг к каждому серверу

Comment: @user190134 Если пинг нужен именно до майнкрафт-сервера, а не до веб-сервера, то сделать это из браузера невозможно

Comment: @andreymal а каким способом это можно сделать?

Comment: @user190134 только установив пользователю какую-нибудь программу, у которой будет доступ к обычным сокетам

Comment: @andreymal  ну почему же? Если есть сетевое взаимодействие, то время отклика скорее всего можно замерить. Делаем ajax-запрос на хост:порт и замеряем время до получения ответа

Comment: @rjhdby ага-ага: резолвинг DNS, TCP handshake, TLS handshake, проверка что сертификат не отозван, HTTP запрос в нескольких пакетах, ожидание тормознутого апача, HTTP-ответ в нескольких пакетах... И вместо ожидаемых ~50мс можем легко получить секунды три

Comment: @andreymal а при чем тут апач?

Comment: @rjhdby ну пусть даже nginx+php-fpm — вы ожидаете, что веб-сервер будет настолько идеально написан, что не будет тормозить при обработке ajax-запроса? Мне бы ваш оптимизм)

Comment: @andreymal а при чем тут вообще веб-сервер?

Comment: @rjhdby а каким таким чудом вы собрались делать ajax-запрос на хост:порт, если на этом порту не будет веб-сервера?

Comment: @andreymal может для вас это будет новостью, но сетевые протоколы не ограничиваются http. И коннект надо проверять до игрового сервера, а не до его странички

Comment: @rjhdby может для вас это будет новостью, но ajax-запросы работают по протоколу http и ни по какому другому

Comment: @andreymal вообще, нам совершенно без разницы, какие там протоколы. Нам нужно исключительно пульнуть пакет в сторону сервера и получить ответ/ошибку. Всё.

Comment: @andreymal да и ajax тут только к слову был. Веб-сокеты и прочие способы работы с сетью никто не отменял

Comment: @rjhdby у меня кончились разумные аргументы, но ваш способ почему-то всё равно не работает: я попробовал попинговать вашим способом свой сервер, но вместо ожидаемых ~8мс получил ~100-400мс

Comment: @andreymal и тут мы возвращаемся к первому предложению моего ответа :) Насколько я понял задачу - нужны не конкретные цифры, а относительные попугаи, показывающие, какой сервер отвечает быстрее

Comment: @rjhdby я стучусь на закрытый порт, чтобы сервер ответил connection refused и до ajax/вебсокетов и даже до TCP handshake дело вообще не дошло. Я даже заменил домен на ip-адрес и получил ~40мс, но как с вашими ответами получить правильные ~8мс, я всё равно не понимаю

Comment: @rjhdby в играх важны именно конкретные цифры, ибо ~40мс для кого-то это уже неиграбельно :)